# thread safe queue implementation

Tags: c, multithreading

In my application I have 2 threads plus the main thread.

One thread is to obtain data (4096 bytes to a buffer) from the I/O module when an interrupt occurs. And the other thread is to consume this data (process and format and write the data to a file).

What would be the best method to achieve this?

I can't lose data from the producer thread which happens at a fast rate.

Any examples i can study on this will be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to implement thread safe queues and having a hard time.

i am sorry i forgot to include the platform and other infomation.
i am using windows xp(32bit) and Microsoft visual studio 5.0 compiler.

Comment: This is going to depend on the operating system/platform you're planning to target. As far as I know C doesn't provide threading primitives as standard. (The closest thing to it is probably pthreads, but that's not available on every platform.)

Comment: Well, c11 provides threading but support is, shall we say, intermittent :-)

Comment: Yes, exactly what platform/architecture/compiler and you using?

Comment: This is called the "producer-consumer problem". Searching the web for it should give you a lot of different algorithms that solve this problem and a lot of implementations for commonly used programming languages and platforms.

Comment: A circular ring buffer will be the simplest solution if you intent to stay with one thread on each side. Newer Linux distros provide you with http://linux.die.net/man/3/vrb which is handy for those purposes. As soon as you need more then one thread to access either side you will have to start dealing with locks and synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make an assumption for are on POSIX platform.

Use [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)

Then the consumer can nick the grub whilst the producer is blind.

SORRY FOR THE [Metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor)

Comment: @fork0 - Oops. Corrected the post.